# How can I trigger window.open to a specific dynamic URL?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, window.open

I would like to open a new tab with sent condition, my code now:

```
<span>Type <b>Link</b>: <input id="myInput" value=""> and click <b>Enter</b> 
<button style="display: none;" id="myButton" onclick="myFunction2()">Go!</button>

[...]

<script>
var websitelink = '"https://www.' + myInput + '.com"';
function myFunction2() {
    window.open(websitelink);
}
```

but all it does is opening a new blank tab. Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Open your developer's tools in your browser (F12) and look at the Console tab. Any errors reported there? And, you do have a closing `<script>` tag as well, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more quotes than you need in your websitelink

It should work with this:

```
var websitelink = "https://www." + myValue + ".com";
```

Here it's a snippet:

**The code in a website should work but the snippet will not work because the allow-popups permission is not set in the iframe**

> Blocked opening 'https://www.google.es.com/' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

```js
function myFunction2() {
    var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var websitelink = "https://www." + myInput + ".com";
    window.open(websitelink);
}
```

```html
<span>Type <b>Link</b>: <input id="myInput" value=""> and click <b>Enter</b> 
<button style="" id="myButton" onclick="myFunction2()">Go!</button>
```

Comment: @Maciej This is the correct answer. If it's still not working you have some other issue.

Comment: @Maciej Check it out the edit of my answer, it probably what you are experimenting. You can see the error message in the console.

Comment: Popup blockers do not typically block a new window that opens as a result of a user action, like  button click because not all pop ups are bad. They only block pop ups when the code automatically generates the pop up without user intervention.